# IBM Cloud with Watson Assistant: "Unknown error, Code: 422" returned for API call

Tags: python-3.x, ibm-cloud, watson-assistant

I'm trying to use Watson Assistant from the CLI with a Python script, similar to the demo [Building a custom client](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/assistant?topic=assistant-api-client). The Python script is:

```
from ibm_watson import AssistantV2
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

# Create Assistant service object.
authenticator = IAMAuthenticator(api_key_for_wa_service) # replace with API key
assistant = AssistantV2(
    version = '2020-09-24',
    authenticator = authenticator
)
assistant.set_service_url('https://api.au-syd.assistant.watson.cloud.ibm.com')
assistant_id = '00965b15-eb3f-4d83-8983-3df0c7da9c4f'

# Start conversation with empty message:
response = assistant.message_stateless(assistant_id, 
                                        ).get_result()
```

I think it's connecting okay, but the request is failing with status code 422:

```
c:\Runnable>python create_watson_assistant_service_object.py
Method failed with status code 422: Unknown error
```

I've tried passing an input argument after the assistant_id argument in the request:

```
input = {'message_type': 'text', 'text': 'Hello'}
```

This gives the same result (code 422).

I don't know what to try next.

Comment: Could add the full error message with the call stack? Could you add error handling as documented here? https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2?code=python#error-handling

Comment: The new output (from new exception handling code) is now shown.

Comment: Can you confirm that it is exactly the code above (I don't see any exception handling)? Is only that single line of error message printed? Your API key is the current one for Watson Assistant? You Assistant ID is the one matching the one shown for your assistant? Your SDK is up to date?

Comment: @data_henrik I changed the `create_session` call as follows:
`response = assistant.create_session(assistant_id = assistant_id).get_result()` and followed it with `print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))`.
Now it responds with the session_id, so that's progress. However, the response does not include the "output" field (or any other). This is not working as shown in the documentation.
Is there something about the V2 Python API that has changed?

Comment: Is there no output if the assistant is created on a Lite plan?

Answer (score 1):

It is not clear, what `assistant_id` is being set to. `my_assistant_id` isn't initialised anywhere in your code snippet.

```py
assistant_id = my_assistant_id
```

You also are not providing any input. From the API documentation - https://cloud.ibm.com/apidocs/assistant/assistant-v2?code=python#messagestateless

```py
import json
from ibm_watson import AssistantV2
from ibm_cloud_sdk_core.authenticators import IAMAuthenticator

authenticator = IAMAuthenticator('{apikey}')
assistant = AssistantV2(
    version='2020-04-01',
    authenticator = authenticator
)

assistant.set_service_url('{url}')

response = assistant.message_stateless(
    assistant_id='{assistant_id}',
    input={
        'message_type': 'text',
        'text': 'Hello'
    }
).get_result()

print(json.dumps(response, indent=2))
```

Comment: Thanks. I was using `my_assistant_id` as a dummy, in the example code. Actually, it is set to '00965b15-eb3f-4d83-8983-3df0c7da9c4f' before the request. Looking at your 2nd comment now.

Comment: Okay, so I was already basing my code on that reference. I used the same snippet as you showed, and got the same result: 422.